# How to answer to this algebra problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, factorial

Thanks for your attention to this question, here is the problem:

Compute the number of positive integers $x$ less than or equal to $1000$ that satisfy the following condition:
$$x! \text{ is divisible by } 1+2+3+...+x$$

Comment: Do you recall a formula for $1 + 2 + \dots + x$?

Comment: @JavaMan- of course i know it.

Comment: Do you you see a way to use it?

Comment: @Victor: If you know the formula, you can simplify it to get an equivalent version of your question which is $x$ such that $(x+1)| (2 \times (x-1)!)$. Can you now proceed from here and argue out what $x$ should be?

Comment: @JavaMan - no, i don't see it

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran - i don't know how to get to there...

Comment: @Victor: What is the formula for $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + x$?

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran - it is x(x+1)/2

Comment: So you need $\frac{x!}{x(x+1)/2} = k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Rearrange to get what I have written earlier. Can you then take it from there.

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran -But i don't know if there are "shortcut" to continue, otherwise i have to check all the cases.

Comment: Why don't you try a few examples for $x$ and see what happens? Then try to generalize. You will see the pattern immediately when you try out the examples.

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran - i hate induction because it can't solve many problem when the problem is complicated

Comment: @Victor: Why don't you try out some examples for $x$? You will see it will fail for some of them. If you just want the solution I can write it out.

Comment: @SivaramAmbikasaran - May you use a solution not using induction?

Comment: Victor, can you tell us where you took the problem from?

Comment: @Srivatsan -new york city interscholastic math league , but i change the number

Comment: why so many down-votes for this one?

Comment: @MaX: possibly because of the obstinate helplessness the OP clings to in the comment thread?

Comment: @Henning Makholm:May be yes, but the problem itself is not so bad; +1 from my side :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need to find $x$ such that $x!$ is divisible by $1+2+3+\cdots+x$. Note that $$1+2+\cdots + x = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$
Hence, we need $\frac{x!}{x(x+1)/2} = k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ i.e. $\frac{2 \times (x-1)!}{x+1} = k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Now we split it into five cases:

$1$. $x+1$ is an odd prime. If $x+1$ is an odd prime i.e. a prime greater than $2$, then we need $x+1$ to divide one of the numbers in the set $\{1,\ldots,x-1\} \cup \{2\}$ . But all the numbers in the set are smaller than $x+1$ and hence $x+1$ cannot divide any of the numbers. Hence, when $x+1$ is an odd prime, we cannot have $\frac{2 \times (x-1)!}{x+1}$ to be an integer whenever $x+1$ is an odd prime.

$2$. $x+1 = 2$. This can be easily checked that $x!$ is divisible by $1+2+3+\cdots+x$ i.e. $1!$ is divisible by $1$.

$3$. If $x+1$ is a composite number and is not of the form $p^2$, where $p$ is a prime, then it is not an irreducible. Hence $x+1 = ab$ where $1 < a < b<x+1$. Further note that in fact we have $a < b < x$. If $x|(x+1)$, then $x | (x+1-x)$ i.e. $x | 1$ i.e. $x=1$ which is not possible. Hence, if $x+1$ is a composite number, then $x+1 = ab$ where $1 < a < b < x$. Note that this means 
$$
\begin{align}
(x-1)! & = 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times (a-1) \times a \times \cdots \times (b-1) \times b \times \cdots \times (x-1)\\
& = ab \times \left( 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times (a-1) \times (a+1) \times \cdots \times (b-1) \times (b+1) \times \cdots \times (x-1) \right)\\
& = (x+1) \times \left( 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times (a-1) \times (a+1) \times \cdots \times (b-1) \times (b+1) \times \cdots \times (x-1) \right)
\end{align}$$
Hence, $x+1$ divides $(x-1)!$.

$4$. If $x+1$ is a composite number of the form $p^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then it immediately follows that $2p<p^2-1$. Hence, a similar argument as $3$, by grouping $p$ and $2p$, gives us that $x+1$ divides $(x-1)!$.

$5$. If $x+1$ is $2^2$, then again we can easily check that $4| \left(2 \times 2! \right)$.

Hence, when $x+1$ is a composite number (or) $2$, we have that $(x+1) | \left( 2 \times (x-1)! \right)$.

Hence, the numbers you are interested are $$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}^+: x+1 \text{ is composite (or) }x+1 = 2\}$$

Comment: I think you need to be slightly more careful when $x+1 = p^2$, in which case we'll have $a = b$ ($= p$). [I don't think the final answer changes though.]

Comment: @Srivatsan: Thanks for pointing that out! It is actually an important piece in the proof.